# How do I animate a UIImageView on tap gesture?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, cocoapods, uitapgesturerecognizer

So for my app, I have two UIImageViews that have tap gestures. Don't ask why I didn't use buttons; it just made sense at the time for my situation. So here's my problem:
They work, and everything is fine and dandy, but there is zero response out of the box for tap gesture recognizer. Does anybody know an easy library or some simple code that can at LEAST make the UIImageView "pop" on tap, or something like that? I am really just looking for any way to animate these views on tap, so the user feels like they're actually doing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since animation is basically a change of appearance you could change UIImageView's alpha for a second...

This example functions changes `yourImageView.alpha` to `0.75` and during `0.5 seconds` back to `1.0`.

**Swift 2:**

```
func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

       yourImageView.alpha = 0.75
       UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
            yourImageView.alpha = 1.0
       }
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    yourImageView.alpha = 0.75
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { 
        yourImageView.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, coming in clutch. This is a pretty crafty method! I assume I could tinker with this too and probably add more effects later. Anyways, selecting this answer, thanks again!

Comment: sure you can do with it whatever you want like adding a border for a second or whatever. just change it to what you want "for a short amount of time" outside the animate block and then change it back within the animate block. always glad to help